# function to combine multiple lists by factors in R

Tags: r

This is what I am trying to do. I need to write a function, let us call it `combine` which takes in multiple lists and combines them. To pass multiple lists to the function, I need to use ellipsis as argument for the function. What I can't figure out is how to combine the lists inside the function properly.

The lists (all of which have a common structure) which will be passed to the function have multiple factors, a few of which are matrices and others numeric vectors. So, for example, the lists look like

```
     list1 <- list(a= matrix(), b=numeric(), c=numeric())
```

I need to define a function like this:

```
    combine <- function(...) {

       #get all lists as lists or something that is convenient
       all_lists <- list(...)

       #define a list which will be returned
       l <- list(a= list(), b=numeric(), c=numeric())

       #l$a <- combine factor 'a' of all input lists as lists, use list()
       #l$b <- cbind factor 'b' of all input lists as data frame, use cbind()
       #l$c <- set union of elements of factor 'c' of input lists, use union()

       return(l)
    }
```

So, if I pass three lists to the function, the output should be like

```
    >l1 <- list(a= matrix(c(1:20), 10,2), b=c(1:11), c= c(1:5))
    >l2 <- list(a= matrix(c(21:40), 10,2), b=c(11:21), c= c(2:7))
    >l2 <- list(a= matrix(c(41:60), 10,2), b=c(21:31), c= c(3:6))

    >l <- combine(l1, l2, l3)
    >l$a[1]
    [[1]]
          [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    1   11
    [2,]    2   12
    [3,]    3   13
    [4,]    4   14
    [5,]    5   15
    [6,]    6   16
    [7,]    7   17
    [8,]    8   18
    [9,]    9   19
    [10,]   10   20
    > l$b[4,3]
    [1] 24
    > l$c
    [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: yeah but `c` just binds all the lists together, it does not do the kind of reformatting by factors which my function needs to do.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `lapply` to go through all the lists and extract the a, b, or c from each and combine those lists how you need to. You have a; for b, you can use `do.call('cbind', ...)` to `cbind` a list of things; and for c just `union` or get all the unique elements

```
l1 <- list(a= matrix(c(1:20), 10,2), b=c(1:11), c= c(1:5))
l2 <- list(a= matrix(c(21:40), 10,2), b=c(11:21), c= c(2:7))
l3 <- list(a= matrix(c(41:60), 10,2), b=c(21:31), c= c(3:6))

combine <- function(...) {
  all_lists <- list(...)
  l <- list()
  l$a <- lapply(all_lists, '[[', 'a')
  l$b <- do.call('cbind', lapply(all_lists, '[[', 'b'))
  l$c <- Reduce(union, lapply(all_lists, '[[', 'c'))
  ## or 
  # l$c <- unique(unlist(lapply(all_lists, '[[', 'c')))
  l
}

l <- combine(l1, l2, l3)

l$a[1]
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1   11
# [2,]    2   12
# [3,]    3   13
# [4,]    4   14
# [5,]    5   15
# [6,]    6   16
# [7,]    7   17
# [8,]    8   18
# [9,]    9   19
# [10,]   10   20

l$b[4,3]
# [1] 24

l$c
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please elaborate on what `'[['` is doing? Looks like you use it as a function but I wasn't aware that it could be used as a function.

Comment: @MrK everything in r is a function. try this: `\`[\`(c('a','b'), 2)` the way I used `[[` is just short-hand for something like `lapply(all_lists, function(x) x[['c']])`. that might be easier to see what's going on but the other way saves you from having to use an anonymous function and looks slightly cleaner IMO

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see how your desired output came to be, but according to your question, here's a function that does the following:

- Take slot `a` of each list and bind them all into a list.
- Take slot `b` of each list and bind them into a matrix.
- Take slot `c` of each list and unite.

---

```
combine <- function(...) {

   #get all lists as lists or something that is convenient
   all_lists <- list(...)

   la <- lapply(all_lists, function(x) x$a)
   lb <- sapply(all_lists, function(x) x$b)
   lc <- unique( do.call(c,sapply(all_lists, function(x) x$c)) )

   #define a list which will be returned
   return(list(a=la,b=lb,c=lc))
}

l1 <- list(a= matrix(c(1:20), 10,2), b=c(1:11), c= c(1:5))
l2 <- list(a= matrix(c(21:40), 10,2), b=c(11:21), c= c(2:7))
l3 <- list(a= matrix(c(41:60), 10,2), b=c(21:31), c= c(3:6))

combine(l1,l2,l3)
```

Comment: I just gave a sample of what I expected the desired output to be. It did not really come into being before your answer. :) Also, you missed quotes around `c` in `do.call`. Thank you for the answer. I was trying to use lapply but it did not occur to me that I could just return relevant factors.

Comment: @MrK - Did I? I believe `do.call` doesn't need quotes in that case. It is sufficient to name the function here, see `?do.call`.

Comment: hmm. well, i got an error when i tried your code. So, I put `c` in quotes and it worked.